# Python matplotlib colorbars: all on last axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

All of my colorbars appear on the last `imshow()` axis:

[image: All scalebars stuck to the bottom-most image]

Here is my code:

```
"""
Least replicable unit
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
number = 3
Images = np.random.rand(400, number)
Spectra = np.random.rand(100, number)

fig, cax = plt.subplots(nrows=number, ncols=2)
for i in range(number):
    cax[i, 0].plot(Spectra[:, i])
    P = cax[i, 1].imshow(Images[:,i].reshape((20, 20)))
    fig.colorbar(P)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Just wanted to acknowledge that this is a really nice and refreshing first question. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the axis instance to the `colorbar` as an argument as follows. I have highlighted the modified line by a comment. Rest of the code remains the same

```
for i in range(number):
    cax[i, 0].plot(Spectra[:, i])
    P = cax[i, 1].imshow(Images[:,i].reshape((20, 20)))
    fig.colorbar(P, ax=cax[i, 1]) # Modified here
    plt.tight_layout()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks to all! I appreciate the help and comments.